# 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
from decimal import Decimal

variable = input("Introduce una variable: ")
tipos = [float, int, Decimal, complex, str]

for tipo in tipos:
    if (variable == tipo[0]):
       print("Esta variable es de tipo real")
    elif (variable != tipo[0]):
        print("Esta variable no es de tipo real")
    elif (variable == tipo[1] or variable == tipo[2]):
        variablenueva = float(variable)
    else:
        if (variable == tipo[3]):
            print("No se puede transformar a real un numero complejo")
```

Comment: Pista: Para saber el tipo de algo es tan fácil como `print("Esta variable es de tipo "+str(type(variable)))` y te ahorras mucho lio.

Comment: Francisco, creo que has leído mi respuesta a tu anterior pregunta, pero me parece que sigues con la confusión, `variable`  es una cadena, un objeto `str` siempre lo será, independientemente de lo que ingreses. No tiene sentido verificar el tipo de dato, por que siempre es un `str`. Por otro lado, `tipo[n]` siempre va a ser inválido, por que `tipo` será alguno de los elementos de `tipos` es decir `[float, int, Decimal, complex, str]` y ninguno de estos es `subscriptable` o indizable, como lo es una lista por ejemplo.

Comment: Trata de definir en palabras lo que buscas hacer, que seguramente será más fácil poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo primero decirte que podrías explicarnos un poco cuál es la funcionalidad que esperas de ese código. Porque lo leo un poco por encima y me saltan algunas dudas. También deberías poner que versión de Python estás usando, es realmente importante.

**Contestando a porqué te está dando ese error:**

- Tienes un `array` de `type`s el cual recorres.
- Por cada `type` estas intentando acceder a la posición `[0]` de ese `type`.
- **Los `type` no son subscriptable** quiere decirte, que el objeto `type` no contiene elementos a los que puedas acceder con una posición.

Si quieres acceder a la posición del array especificándoselo con `[posición]` debes quitar el bucle `for`.
Otra solución es quitar los `[posición]`, ya que en `tipo` ya tienes el `type` para comparar.

**Otras consideraciones:**
He leído en los comentarios que la `input()` siempre va a devolverte un `str`. Esto solo es cierto si usas `Python3`. En el caso de de la Built-in Function `input()` de la versión de `Python2.7` se comporta como un `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
Por lo tanto, sí que te va a devolver un objeto del tipo que encuentre.
[Python2 input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)
[Python3 input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

*Notas:

- Para introducir un `str` hay que escribirlo entre comillas.
- Esta función no captura errores de usuario.

**Cómo saber el typo de una variable:**
Como te comentan en los comentarios también, la función `type` te devuelve el tipo de la variable. Por lo que debes usarla.
Otra opción es usar [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

**Ejemplo de código:**
Si detallas un poco cuál es el comportamiento deseado puedo intentar arreglar el código según digas.